# Segue following a change in criteria from a local notification in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uilocalnotification

I have created a local notification in Swift which gives the option to end a current game without having to go back in to the app. That's all fine and works as it should. The issue I'm having is that if the user does this, I don't want them to go back to the Game view controller if that happens to be the last view that was open when the app entered the background. I would like them to go back to the app's Home view controller instead.

I expected to be able to add a perform segue to my Game view controller in the following way, should the criteria match. I tried adding it to viewDidAppear(), but it didn't work:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if isThereACurrentGame() == false {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToHomeScreen", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Is this something to do with viewDidAppear() not being called when the app comes back to the foreground? If so, what might an alternative be?

P.S. My isThereACurrentGame() function works as it should, as does the performSegueWithIdentifier elsewhere in the view controller, so these aren't the cause of the problem.